# How much memory slots in Lenovo Ideapad 100-15IBD

Tags: laptop, memory, motherboard, lenovo-laptop

How much memory slots in Lenovo Ideapad 100-15IBD and they are soldered? (80QQ004GFR)

Official website tells me: this laptop have 2 so-dimm slots and support up to 8Gb max (http://support.lenovo.com/fr/fr/products/Laptops-and-netbooks/100-series/100-15ibd/parts/PD100815).

Same time in internetshops in english/frensh/german languages for model 100-15IB**D** you can find from "1 memory slot and soldered" up to "2 memory slots, 1 busy with 4Gb and 1 empty".

it's a model with 5005u, 4Gb ram and integrated video.

Comment: Here is your service manual, only 1 removable dimm  https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/ideapad_100_15_ibd_hmm_201508.pdf

Comment: The manual is not clear, in specifications section it says Sodimm x2, but in the memory replace section it only shows one, so maybe there is one soldered. You would just need to open it up and look to see how many dimm slots there are.

Comment: i want to know it before buying this laptop. 5005u enought for my work but i need 8Gg ram inside.

Comment: same time on page 26 in table written: SODIMM × 2 , but maybe it's only for version with nvidia N16V-GM because in this review ( http://laptopmedia.com/news/inside-lenovo-ideapad-100-disassembly-internal-photos-and-upgrade-options/ ) people told that it's only 1 slot.

Comment: When in doubt do not buy, the documentation is poor on that model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, here is [the answer](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-IdeaPad-100-305-500-Edge/How-much-memory-slots-in-Lenovo-Ideapad-100-15IBD-80QQ004GFR/m-p/2247719/highlight/false#M36465)

> The machine technically has 2 slots, but only one is user accessible,
>   the other is soldered on
>
> The machine can come with the following configs
>
> - 4 GB - 1 x 4GB module in replaceable slot
> - 6 GB - 1 x 4GB module in replaceable slot + 1 x 2 GB onboard memory
> - 8 GB - 1 x 8GB module in replaceable slot

Comment: Just an additional explanation: is the accessible slot the one I can fill with an additional RAM or it is the one with already the RAM in? I am asking because using CPU-Z I see 2 slots (#1 empty and #2 with 4 GB), but using the system scan from crucial I see I have one slot only available and it looks like it is already filled with 4 GB. The fact is that I would like to increase the RAM to 8GB